# Using Sheet to edit and remove items from list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a requirement that when the user clicks element of the list, a sheet should open with information of the selected item and with the button to delete it. I've had some problems with dismissing sheet etc. and this is the best code I figured out:

```swift
import SwiftUI


struct MyTest1: View {
    @StateObject private var listItems = StateItems.items
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    private var isEmptyList: Bool {
        get {
            listItems.items.count == 0
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isEmptyList {
                Text("No items in list!")
            } else {
                ListView()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyTest1()
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject private var listItems = StateItems.items
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State private var sheetView: SheetView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(listItems.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        showingSheet = true
                        sheetView = SheetView(itemToRemove: item, isPresented: $showingSheet)
                    }) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>(
//                        get: { (sheetView.itemToRemove == item) && showingSheet },
                        get: { showingSheet },
                        set: { newIsPresented in
                            print("setting isPresented?  \(newIsPresented)")
                            showingSheet = newIsPresented
                            sheetView = SheetView(itemToRemove: "no item", isPresented: $showingSheet)
//                            listItems.objectWillChange.send()
                        }
                    ), onDismiss: {
                        print("dismiss!")
                    }) {
                        sheetView
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    listItems.delete(at: indexSet)
                })
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("printin all items")
                print(listItems.items)
            } , label: {
                Text("Print items")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    let itemToRemove: String
    
    @StateObject private var listItems = StateItems.items
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                listItems.delete(item: itemToRemove)
                dismiss()
                isPresented = false
            }, label: {
                Label("delete \(itemToRemove)", systemImage: "trash")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
        }
    }
}

class StateItems {
    static let items = ListItems()
}

class ListItems: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "item 3 ;-)"]
    
    func delete(item: String) {
        items = items.filter { $0 != item }
        print(items)
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { (i) in
            let itemToDelete = items[i]
            print(itemToDelete)
            delete(item: itemToDelete)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

It works almost fine except when the user clicks the last item in the list at the very first time, the sheet is frozen. How to solve this?

I need solution working both with sheet and fullScreenCover.
Note that my items in `ListItems` cannot implement Identifiable interface because it comes from external source (I use kotlin multiplatform). If so, then it has to be mapped to another list which is refreshed based on changes in items property.

Comment: Why are you using a sheet?  It is probably the wrong view for this use case.  You could show a confirmation dialog or you could use a navigation view and show a detail page.

Comment: Use only one source of truth,
 `@StateObject private var listItems = ListItems()` in your top view hierarchy.
 Then pass that model to the other views using `.environmentObject(listItems)`.
And in the receiving views, `@EnvironmentObject var listItems: ListItems`. See the official info at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app  Note you need to do this explicitly for `.sheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `StateItems` - It looks like you are trying to use that to provide a static (which is really just a global).  You should have a single state object which you can either pass to child views or put in the environment. Your `ListItems` object is all that you need.

In SwiftUI, things are a lot simpler if your items are `Identifiable`. It typically isn't too hard to add conformance to `Identifiable`.

Create a wrapper struct for your item that conforms to `Identifiable`

```
struct ListItem:Identifiable {
    var value: String
    var id = UUID()
}

class ListItems: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [ListItem(value: "Item 1"), ListItem(value:"Item 2"), ListItem(value:"item 3 ;-)"),ListItem(value:"Item 2")]
    
    func delete(item: ListItem) {
        items = items.filter { $0.id != item.id }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        offsets.forEach { (i) in
            let itemToDelete = items[i]
            delete(item: itemToDelete)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Now, create a `@StateObject` at the root view and pass it to sub views through the environment

```
struct MyTest1: View {
    @StateObject private var listItems = ListItems()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if listItems.items.isEmpty {
                Text("No items in list!")
            } else {
                ListView().environmentObject(listItems)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyTest1()
}
```

Because your `ListItem` conforms to `Identifiable`,  `ListView` can be a lot simpler, with an optional `selectedItem` to manage the appearance of the sheet:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var listItems: ListItems
    @State private var selectedItem: ListItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(listItems.items) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedItem = item
                    }) {
                        Text(item.value)
                    }
                    .sheet(item: $selectedItem, content: { item in
                        SheetView(itemToRemove: item)
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    listItems.delete(at: indexSet)
                })
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("printin all items")
                print(listItems.items)
            } , label: {
                Text("Print items")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, your `SheetView` is pretty straight-forward. Again, it gets the `ListItems` from the environment.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    let itemToRemove: ListItem
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listItems: ListItems
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                listItems.delete(item: itemToRemove)
                dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Label("delete \(itemToRemove.value)", systemImage: "trash")
                    .padding()
                    .background(.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added init() to SheetView and it seems that is creating new view with same itemToRemove as many times as there are items in the list, every time you click to show the sheet.

Comment: Yes, that is quite possible. SwiftUI creates views as if needs to. Views should be very lightweight structs so there should be little impact from this. As I commented earlier, a sheet isn't the UI I would use. If you just want the user to confirm deletion, I would use an `Alert`. If you want to show detail with a delete button, use a `NavigationView` and navigate to a detail page.